# Run lppchk within a variable - AIX

Tags: ksh

When I try to do this :

```
LPPCHK=`lppchk -v`
if [[ "$LPPCHK" != "" ]]
then
    echo "$LPPCHK"
fi
```

But it always runs the "lppchk" when it gets to the variable, echo's it to the screen and doesn't save it within the variable..??..  This is the only command I have seen do this, all others work fine in this scenario..

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The code does what your asks:
Perform `lppchk -v` in a subshell, capture the stdout (normal output) and put that in the variable LPPCHK.
Check that LPPCHK is filled and echo the contents.
So why do you see the result of `lppchk -v` before the if-statement?

When `lppchk -v` writes its output to stderr, you will still see it on your screen (console). You can redirect stderr to stdout with

```
LPPCHK=`lppchk -v 2>&1`
# Another notation, using $() and avoiding backtics
LPPCHK=(lppchk -v 2>&1) 
# Also consider using lowercase shell variables
```

Comment: The problem is no matter how I do my variable, tried both examples, it still echo's the lppchk command right away and my "LPPCHK" variable is empty.  I can put any other command in the variable and it works the way it is suppose to.  Is there something special with the lppchk command that it acts different?  I only have 1 system with an lpp issue right now so I was trying to get my script to work before I fix it..

Comment: First try to redirect the output without an assignment to a variable. When you know how to get lppchk silent, you know what descriptor (1, 2 or maybe even 3 or 4) needs to be redirected: `lppchk -v > /dev/null` or `lppchk -v 2> /dev/null` or `lppchk -v 3> /dev/null`. I hope lppchk isn't triggering another process that is running in the background, output of that process is hard to capture (try a new window) !